# Caliburn Application.Resources doesn't work, why ? how to make it work?

Tags: wpf, caliburn

why when trying to add some resource dictionaries to my CaliburnApplication.Resources tag, it does not work, and when do it in code behind of my app.xaml it works?

Comment: Can you post examples of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're using Caliburn?  I would update to their latest version, as the CaliburnApplication class indicates you are on an older one.  Svn checkout their latest and build from source.

You can also take a look at this [caliburn discussion](http://caliburn.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=234317).  It could be related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not?
My advice is to crate ResourceDictionaries for all your styles etc, one dictionary for each style (if there are not too many), and then merge them all i App.xaml by

```
  <Application.Resource>
      <ResourceDictionary><ResourceDictionary.MergeDictionaries>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="your path to source resourcedictionary"/>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="your path to nextsource resourcedictionary"/>
          ....
```

This enables more easy management of all your resources, styles etc. Easier to read, understand and better maintanance over time!

Comment: My problem is that I'm working with the <CaliburnApplication/> tag and its not working